# How to reduce the TTFB time for drupal website

Tags: javascript, php, html, drupal, drupal-7

I am using Drupal 7 and My website takes very long time to load the home page and other inner pages.
Actually website homepage have lots of images and videos. Homepage have almost 85 images and 18 videos as video slider.

I am also using CDN for Drupal project.

I have tried to compress the image and video.
Also i have enabled the Drupal cache and aggregate all JS and CSS but its not affecting much in speed.

TTFB takes almost 7-8 seconds during page load.

Any Idea?

Comment: perhaps try disabling modules one by one to see which one is taking longer to generate response. It's hard to tell what might be the issue with just this information. So, try reading this this thoroughly : https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/managing-site-performance-and-scalability/optimizing-drupal-to-load-faster-server-mysql

Comment: Open developer console (F12 key usually), go to network tab and reload the page. Check on request times, is first page slow, or some specific file or just sum of all the media files is too big. See what causes the biggest delay.

Comment: 85 images sounds like a lot, can you implement some degree of lazy loading to only fetch the images when they need to be displayed on screen?